# updating a model attribute in django using form

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to update a model field in my django app. the application is such that there are two models, Project and Contractor. and their relation is like each project can assign multiple contractors and each contractor can work on multiple projects..and both project and contractor are associated to a Client Model..my models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):    ## the client is the user
   user=models.OneToOneField(User)
   def __unicode__(self):
   return self.user.username

class Contractor(models.Model): ##unhired contractors
   name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
   url=models.URLField()
   bill_rate=models.IntegerField(default=0)
   slug=models.SlugField(unique=True)
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   self.slug=slugify(self.name)
   super(Contractor, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
   def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Project(models.Model):
   contractor=models.ManyToManyField(Contractor, null=True)
   client=models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=True)
   title=models.CharField(max_length=128)
   slug=models.SlugField(unique=True)
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.slug=slugify(self.title)
       super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.title
```

and forms.py is:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title=forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug=forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
    class Meta:
       model=Project
       fields=('title','contractor')

class ContractorForm(forms.ModelForm): ##the contractor first register itself separately and is later added to the project while a project is been created
    name=forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter your name or your firm's name: ")
    bill_rate=forms.IntegerField(initial=0, help_text="Please enter your Bill rate")
    url=forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter your web-details: ")
    slug=forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
    class Meta:
       model=Contractor
       fields=('name','bill_rate','url',)
```

and here is the view in which i'm trying to update my contractor attribute:

```
  def addContractorToUnaddedProjects(request):
     if request.method=="POST":
        project=ProjectForm(request.POST)
        if project.is_valid():
           project.save(commit=True)
        else:
           print project.errors
     else: 
       project=ProjectForm()
    return render(request, 'keeper/addContractorToUnaddedProject.html', {'form':update,})
```

so whenever i try run this code instead of updating only the contractor field, a whole new project is created..to update a new contractor for a project i'm directing the project page which currently have no contractor to "addnewcontractor" page & there i'm using project form but instead of using title and contractor both, i'm getting input only for the contractor field..what am i doing wrong here?

here's the html code i am using to update the contractor for already created project:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block title %}Add Contractor{% endblock %}
{% block body_block %}
<h1>Add a Contractor from our available Contractors!!</h1>
<form id="add_contractor_unadded" method="post" action="/keeper/addContractorToUnaddedProject/">
{% csrf_token %}
    <strong><h4>Please select a contractor: {{ form.contractor }}</h4></strong>
<input type="submit" name='submit' value="ADD" />
</form>
<h2><a href="/keeper/dashboard/">Home</a></h2>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is that a typo in Project.objects.get(contractor='contractor')? Shouldn't it be Project.objects.get(contractor__name='contractor')

Comment: yeah actually,whole view was a typo..i just edited it to very basic.can u plz suggest changes as to update the contractor field for the project..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that "each project can assign multiple contractors" but that not how your model works - it allows a single contractor per project:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    contractor=models.ForeignKey(Contractor, null=True)
```

`ForeignKey` if for one to many relationships - here a Project has zero or one Contractor and a Contractor has zero, one or many Projects.

If you want to have many contractors per project, you have to use a many to many relationship, which in Django is built using a `ManyToManyField`:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    contractors = models.ManyToManyField(Contractor, null=True)
```

Now with your view... Well, how to say... It's a total nonsense.

First, you use a `ProjectForm` without passing it a `Project` instance - this is the way to create a new `Project` (using `form.save()` which you don't call), but not to edit an existing one. If you want to edit an existing `Project`, get your `Project` instance and pass it to the form (as documented for modelforms).

Then you have this quadruple nonsense:

```
old_contractor = Project.objects.get(contractor='contractor')
```

This just cannot work... At the very least it should be

```
old_contractor = Project.objects.get(contractor__name='contractor')
```

which would still be a triple nonsense :

1. you name your object 'old_contractor' but it's a `Project`
2. for this to work, you have to have a contractor named "contractor" and it has to have one single project (else you get either an `ObjectDoesNotExist` or a `MultipleObjectsReturned` error
3. you then update this project with the contractor selected in your form.

FWIW, there's not a single chance *this* code creates a new project since you *dont* call the form's `save()` method.

So to answer your question ("what am i doing wrong here?"), I'm afraid the answer is along the line of "everything".

Comment: hey, thanks.. i'm a beginner in django so sorry for the nonsense code..okay, so i just edited it can you now suggest how to update the contractor for a project which was previously created but was not added with any contractor...and also if i want to get the contractor field from the form does, Project.objects.get(pk=1) work here or this is to retreive the value from the existing model field??

Comment: @NightOwl19 Django is fully documented you know. And I already answered your question FWIW : get your project instance (`Project.objects.get(pk=your_project_pk)`, cf the doc for how to pass the pk from the url to your view), pass it to your `ProjectForm` (as documented in the modelforms doc), and save your form back when it has been submitted.

Comment: okk...it is still gonna take me some time, but i will try harder..thanks for your suggestions and help...

Comment: @NightOwl19 yes learning always take some time - but it goes _ways_ faster when you start by doing the tutorials and reading the doc.

Answer (score 0):

This line always creates a new instance. It doesn't update anything.

```
project.save(commit=True)
```

What you need is doing update with form. here is the hint:

```
 project = Project.objects.get(pk = id)
 projectform=ProjectForm(request.POST,instance=project)
    if projectform.is_valid():
       projectform.save(commit=True)
    else:
       print projectform.errors
```

Comment: hey thanks, but previous code was just nogo..i just edited it so now can u suggest any changes.i want to retrieive the new value for contractor and update it with the previously present value in the contractor field of Project model

Comment: Added another answer.

Comment: thanks..so here in the first line how do i know what id or pk value does my contractor attribute already have? is it by default 1? and in your suggestion, where does it retrieves the newly added contractor from the html form?

Comment: ProjectForm  has no contractor field. So why does it will do anything about it?

Comment: in my project model, i've mapped the contractor for each project with the Contractor model..so do i have to include a separate contractor field in ProjectForm as well? i 've only made visible the contractor field in meta class...

Comment: Yes, you have to add.